# Python write to file keylogging bug

Tags: python, text, keylogger

basically I'm writing a keylogger and while testing it seems I pressed something causing my python write function to print out a bunch of random characters. I printed to console and there's no issue so I'm assuming its a write bug.

Input: apple *"enter"*

outputs on my text file:

愧‧㐱㤲㐮㌰㈱㈷਍瀧‧㐱㤲㘮ㄱ㐵㔰਍瀧‧㐱㤲㜮㘵㔳㘰਍氧‧㐱㤲㤮㄰〸㔱਍攧‧㐱〳〮㤴㠵㐴਍攧瑮牥‧㐱ㄳ〮㠳ㄹ㠳਍敔瑳䐠湯⁥ⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭⴭഭ

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
#from pynput import keyboard # for keylogs

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

keys = []

def key_press(key):
    global keys
    start = timer()
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False

    keys.append((key, start))

    if key == Key.enter:
        with open("log-5.txt", "w") as f:
            for key in keys:
                k = str(key).replace("'", "")
                print(k)
                f.write(k + "\n")
        

        keys = []


with Listener(on_press=key_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

I've reduced the code as much as I could. Let me know if I some syntax is off

Comment: put the code that you are using in the question.

Comment: hey @AlbinPaul I've put in the code. I don't think it'd be the code as it stopped working while I hadn't changed anything

Comment: I am not able to reproduce it. can you past the output of the script also.

Comment: Might have been because it was writing to a text file you didn've named. Regardless I seem to have fixed the problem. Not 100% sure what it was but it might have stemmed from the fact I created some of the text files using echo instead of making them by in file.

Comment: If anyone knows what might have happened please let me know I'm very curious